# Get timestamp from date('z') and year

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I know the year and the day of year (0-365).
Is there any way to get back from it to timestamp?

Something like:

```
$day=date('z');
$year=2012;

$timestamp=strtotime($day.'-nd day of '.$year);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

`$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,1,$day,$year);`

It will produce a timestamp where the time is set to 0:00:00.
(I am not sure if it will behave correctly with respect to daylight savings though...)

Check the PHP manual for further details: [PHP: mktime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: Thanks, this help me to save lot of time! Marked as right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe strtotime gets handy here:
`php -r 'echo @date("Y-m-d H:s", strtotime("january 2012 +200 day")).PHP_EOL;'`
In your example `$timestamp = strtotime("january $year +$day day");`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', $day . ' ' . $year);
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I liitle afraid to use classes like this, because in some servers they didn't work, but in future this will be the best solution I think. Thanks!